# Overriding Scala Enumeration Value

Tags: scala, enumeration

As far as I can tell, Scala has definitions for the Enumeration Value class for Value(Int), Value(String), and Value(Int, String).

Does anyone know of an example for creating a new Value subclass to support a different constructor?

For example, If I want to create an Enumeration with Value(Int, String, String) objects, how would I do it? I would like all of the other benefits of using the Enumeration class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Enumeration values are instance of the Val class. This class can be extended and a factory method can be added.

```
object My extends Enumeration {
    val A = Value("name", "x")
    val B = Value("other", "y")
    class MyVal(name: String, val x : String) extends Val(nextId, name)
    protected final def Value(name: String, x : String): MyVal = new MyVal(name, x)
}

scala> My.B.id
res0: Int = 1

scala> My.B.x
res1: String = y
```

Comment: @Thomas Jung : Your idea is brilliant, but I could not use it. There was a warning "  imported `My' is permanently hidden by definition of object  in package"
Finally , I added this line :
type My = Value
to this example and it worked. I still don't understand why,
Could you please explain it ?

Comment: To use `My` enumeration, you must first import it with `import My._` and also add the following code in the `My` object: ` type My = MyVal`, so you can acces to the x val.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in Scala Enumeration has a much simpler meaning than in Java. For your purpose you don't have to subclass Enumeration nor its Value in any way, you just need to instantiate your own type in its companion object as a `val`. This way you'll get the familiar access model of `val value:MyEnum = MyEnum.Value` as you had in Java which is not possible in the example provided by Thomas Jung. There you'll have `def value:My.MyVal = MyEnum.Value` which is kinda confusing as it seems to me besides all the hackiness of the solution. Here's an example of what I propose:

```
class MyEnum(myParam:String)

object MyEnum {
  val Value1 = new MyEnum("any parameters you want")
  val Value2 = new MyEnum("")
  object Value3 extends MyEnum("A different approach to instantialization which also lets you extend the type in place")
}
```

Here you'll find a more complicated example: [Scala Best Practices: Trait Inheritance vs Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7700507/485115)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer doing it by extending the `Enumeration.Val` class.

For your requirement, I would post a sample below:

```
object FileType extends Enumeration {
  val csv = Val(1,"csv", ",")
  val tsv = Val(2,"tsv", "\t")
  protected case class Val(num: Int, fileType: String, delimiter: String) extends super.Val
  implicit def valueToFileType(x: Value): Val = x.asInstanceOf[Val]
}
```

Accessing values is as below:

```
scala> FileType.csv
res0: FileType.Val = csv

scala> FileType.csv.delimiter
res29: String = ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simpler approach:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Colors extends Enumeration {
  sealed case class Color private[Colors](hexCode: String, name: String) extends Val(name)

  val Black = Color("#000000", "black")
  val White = Color("#FFFFFF", "white")
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object Colors

scala> Colors.Black.hexCode
res0: String = #000000

scala> Colors.Black.name
res1: String = black

scala> Colors.values
res2: Colors.ValueSet = Colors.ValueSet(black, white)

scala>
```