# How does scala.Enumeration.nextName get the identifier text?

Tags: scala, scala.js

[`scala.Enumerator.nextName`](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/scalalib/overrides/scala/Enumeration.scala#L94) and `.nextNameOrNull` currently read:

```
/** The string to use to name the next created value. */
protected var nextName: Iterator[String] = _

private def nextNameOrNull =
  if (nextName != null && nextName.hasNext) nextName.next() else null
```

`nextNameOrNull` is subsequently called to get the name to use for the item being created in the Enumeration.

**How does this code actually achieve this?**

When I copy-paste it into a simple example:

```
class MyBaseClass extends Serializable {
  /** The string to use to name the next created value. */
  protected var nextName: Iterator[String] = _

  private def nextNameOrNull =
    if (nextName != null && nextName.hasNext) nextName.next() else null

  protected final def Value(): Val = Val(nextNameOrNull)

  case class Val(name:String)
}

object MyObject extends MyBaseClass {
  val myValue = Value

  println("Hello from MyObject, myValue: " + myValue)
}
```

it prints: `Hello from MyObject, myValue: Val(null)` instead of the hoped for `Val(myValue)`

What do I need to add to make it work?

Comment: Summary: the cited Enumeration code doesn't actually achieve this (null is always returned) and reflection is used if you follow the call-chain more deeply. Use reflection (a la Enumeration) or a macro (see link in selected answer) to get the same effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala JVM, `Enumeration` [uses reflection](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/ade2ce8623e0d923d922809f2b705732918281bc/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L221) to get the name of the val to which a `Value` was assigned to if `nextNameOrNull` returns null.

In Scala.js, we do not have this luxury (no reflection support). Therefore, the Scala.js compiler *special cases* `scala.Enumeration`, so that code that uses it can work.

If you want to implement some method that knows the name of the `val` it is assigned to, have a look at sbt's [`project` macro](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/a058a38b7b7a4b3959be085b3718ff7afc58bbb3/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Project.scala#L572). Scala's Enumerations could have been implemented that way starting 2.10, but are older.

Comment: Couldn't you just override `nextName` in your concrete implementation of Enumeration? In Scala.js, this works ([test case](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/test-suite/src/test/scala/org/scalajs/testsuite/scalalib/EnumerationTest.scala#L79)).

Comment: Sure, you can even assign the iterator directly to it, but according to `2.10` deprecation docs "Names should be specified individually or discovered via reflection" - it's not a good idea (and definetly not a normal way), it seems like they just forgot to remove it (maybe for reverse compatibility).

Comment: you can override `Value() = Val(nextNameOrNull)` (like in OP's example) - you will receive Val(null), or you can also override it with `Val(myIterator.next)` and receive expected value (there is no need for `nextName /nextNameOrNull`). So encapsulation of this class leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 3):

`nextNameOrNull` isn't not working anymore even for original Scala - as passing a sequence of names to constructor is deprecated and removed. 
Here is the execution for 2.11.2 using original scala's [`Enumeration`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/61caba4bc51b0da5e8ddd0dffc8481df0432b876/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala) (not the replaced one from scala-js):

```
scala> object MyObject extends Enumeration {
     |   val MyValue1, MyValue2 = Value
     | 
     |   println("nextName: " + nextName)
     | }
defined object MyObject

scala> MyObject
nextName: null //still null
```

In `2.10.x` `nextName` used inside one of constructor to specify names explicitly as sequence (which is removed in `2.11.x`):

```
@deprecated("Names should be specified individually or discovered via reflection", "2.10.0")
  def this(initial: Int, names: String*) = {
    this(initial)
    this.nextName = names.iterator
  }
}
```

Now this constructor is removed and `nextName` is just a dead code. Scala uses `populateNameMap()` to provide names for `nameOf` (if they're not specified:

```
private def populateNameMap() {
    val fields = getClass.getDeclaredFields
    def isValDef(m: JMethod) = fields exists (fd => fd.getName == m.getName && fd.getType == m.getReturnType)

    // The list of possible Value methods: 0-args which return a conforming type
    val methods = getClass.getMethods filter (m => m.getParameterTypes.isEmpty &&
                                                   classOf[Value].isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType) &&
                                                   m.getDeclaringClass != classOf[Enumeration] &&
                                                   isValDef(m))
    methods foreach { m =>
      val name = m.getName
      // invoke method to obtain actual `Value` instance
      val value = m.invoke(this).asInstanceOf[Value]
      // verify that outer points to the correct Enumeration: ticket #3616.
      if (value.outerEnum eq thisenum) {
        val id = Int.unbox(classOf[Val] getMethod "id" invoke value)
        nmap += ((id, name))
      }
    }
  }
```

So it uses reflection by default. You can explicitly specify the name for every value as it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507273/overriding-scala-enumeration-value).

I think same for ScalaJs, excluding that it has no `populateNameMap()` method as there is no such kind of reflection for JavaScript - so result for non-explicitly named parameters is:

```
override def toString() =
  if (name != null) name //only if you did `Value("explicitName")` somwhere inside enumeration
  // Scala.js specific
  else s"<Unknown name for enum field #$i of class ${getClass}>"
```

But again, `nextNameOrNull` is dead in both Scala and Scala-Js - it always returns null.