# Parameter string-naming conversion to algebraic types in scala

Tags: scala

In scala I have an algebraic type I would like to work with:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, weight: Float)
```

A library I do not control is providing me values via an enumeration of String values:

```
Enumeration(("name", "Bob"), ("age", "32"), ("weight", "45.64"))
Enumeration(("age", "23"), ("weight", "20.0"), ("name", "Alice"))
```

What's the most "scala-ish" way to get the annoying (name,value) string pairs into my case class?

I've only thought of the obvious iterative CRUD method:

```
def toClass(e: Enumeration[(String,String)]): Person = {
  var name: String = _
  ...
  for(pair <- e) pair._1 match {
    "name" => name = pair._2
  }

  Person(name, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert it to the Map:

```
def toClass(e : Enumeration[(String,String)]) : Person = {
    val raw = e.values.toMap
    Person(raw("name"), raw("age").toInt, raw("weight").toFloat)
}
```

There is also macro-based [universal solution](http://blog.echo.sh/2013/11/04/exploring-scala-macros-map-to-case-class-conversion.html)

P.S. I assume your `Enumeration` is some custom type, as scala's [`Enumeration`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration) doesn't take type parameters and can't hold list of tuples (actually it [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507273/overriding-scala-enumeration-value), but it's not cannonical way to use it). So `e.values` should return list of tuples.