# Can Scala enumeration maps to an Integer like Java?

Tags: java, scala, enums, enumeration

I have an original Java enumeration class, which I can get the corresponding integer value using:

```
Integer blackInteger = ColorEnum.BLACK.getValue()
```

---

```
public enum ColorEnum {

    BLACK(0), BLUE(1), RED(2);

    private int value;

    private ColorEnum(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I then tried to write the enum class in Scala:

```
object ColorEnum extends Enumeration {
  val BLACK, BLUE, RED = Value
}
```

I am wondering how do I get the integer value of ColorEnum.BLACK in Scala?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2508070/406435).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `id` like so:

```
ColorEnum.BLACK.id
```

[Enumeration.Value](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration$Value) in the Scaladoc.

Comment: There's a comment somewhere not to use ordinal in java for logic. It's safer to add a field, since if you change the enum, you change the ordinal. In scala, you can set the id explicitly, `val x = Value(100)`. But because of the bit set impl, it's safer to have a field for big values. By coincidence, I was about to help with https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4803